# How can I stretch a list's height to fit its container?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a left side navbar  with a list of links displayed as a column. I want the list height to fit the available space inside its container, and keeping all the list items stacked on top of the list. here's the structure.

I've tried changing the height, even with a fixed px valor, several displays, it won't budge. It seems the list absolutely want to fit the exact space the list items take.

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #234E53;
  padding-left: 5px;
  max-width: 280px;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

nav {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: medium solid black;
}

.user {
  border: medium solid red;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Validations</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Etudiants</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Entreprise</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Associations</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Missions</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Comptabilité</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Virement à effectuer</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Paramètres</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Setting `height: 100%` on the `ul` should work... Bare in mind, adding extra height to the `ul` won't visually change the `li`, so if you're trying to achieve a certain layout we will need more information.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace after your first style block. That could be disabling the styles that follow. Please revise the snippet I created. Note that a good editor (or just good code formatting) makes problems like this apparent.

Comment: FYI, this is a misuse of heading elements. They should be used to denote content hierarchy, not for styling.

Comment: Assuming you want the sidebar to be the hieght of the viewport then `height:100%` won't be enough . You need to set the height of the `body` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set nav to flex, but you don't have any nav elements - you maybe are missing a . (dot) there.

Even so, you have the flexing on the .sidebar element. This has only one direct child (the ul.nav) so there isn't anything to spread out.

It's the ul that you want spreading vertically.

You also need to make sure that there is a height for it to work to. If you leave it as 100% there is nothing to tell it that you mean the viewport height, so this snippet sets the it to 100vh height.

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: #234E53;
  padding-left: 5px;
  max-width: 280px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.nav{
  margin: 0px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-items: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: medium solid black;
}

.user {
  border: medium solid red;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Validations</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Etudiants</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Entreprise</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Associations</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Missions</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Comptabilité</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Virement à effectuer</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="nav_object">
      <h3>Paramètres</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
```